# Frenet formulas for curves in arbitrary Riemann manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections

As far as I understand, to have Frenet formulas one would need a curve, embedded in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and, desirably, naturally parametized. But there are homonomic notions of curvature and torsion of Levi-Civita connections, associated with Riemann structure of manifold. I wonder whether one can connect these two ideas in one, generalizing the higher curvatures of a curve and corresponding Frenet formulas about this case?